# red light green light in a form powershell

Tags: powershell, draw, geometry, showdialog

trying to use powershell to display a form with a button
the button will perform a test. this is work.
if the test fails the a circle next to the button will be red
vs green. Can this been done ? if so is FillEllipse the right way ?
Do I need to create a new form ?

```
#Load the GDI+ and WinForms Assemblies

`enter code here`[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
# Create pen and brush objects

$myBrush = new-object Drawing.SolidBrush green
$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen black



# Create a Rectangle object for use when drawing rectangle

#$rect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 10, 10, 180, 180



# Create a Form

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)  

$form.text = "Network Connectivity Test"



#$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form



# Get the form's graphics object

$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()



function do-interface {

#

}



#$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 

$Label.Text = "Ethernet 1" 

#$Label.AutoSize = $true 

$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,50) 

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",15,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 

$form.Font = $Font 

$Form.Controls.Add($Label)



# Define the paint handler

$form.add_paint(
{
$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, 350, 80, 15, 15 ) # draw an ellipse using rectangle object

#$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, $rect) # draw an ellipse using rectangle object

}

)

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 

$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,30) 

$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,40) 

$Button.Text = "Interfaces" 

$Button.Add_Click({do-interface}) 

$form.Controls.Add($Button) 
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add FillEllipse to your **do-interface** method

```
$myBrush = new-object Drawing.SolidBrush ("green", "red")[$testFailed]
$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, 350, 80, 15, 15 )
```

Following code will return **green** if *$testFailed* is *$false* or *0* and **red** if it is *$true* or *1*

```
("green", "red")[$testFailed]
```

Also, you don't need to fill ellipse in add_paint. So whole exampel can look like this:

```
#Load the GDI+ and WinForms Assemblies

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
# Create pen and brush objects

$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen black

# Create a Rectangle object for use when drawing rectangle
#$rect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 10, 10, 180, 180

# Create a Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)  
$form.text = "Network Connectivity Test"

#$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
# Get the form's graphics object
$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()

function do-interface {
$testFailed = Get-Random -Maximum 2
Write-Host $testFailed
$myBrush = new-object Drawing.SolidBrush ("green", "red")[$testFailed]
$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, 350, 80, 15, 15 ) # draw an ellipse using rectangle object
}


#$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
#$Label.Text = "Ethernet 1" 
#$Label.AutoSize = $true 
#$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,50) 
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",15,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 
$form.Font = $Font 
#$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

# Define the paint handler

$form.add_paint(
{

#delete this method, if you need it

#$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, $rect) # draw an ellipse using rectangle object

}

)

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 

$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,30) 

$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,40) 

$Button.Text = "Interfaces" 

$Button.Add_Click({do-interface}) 

$form.Controls.Add($Button) 
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```